# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize Interface

Tags: c#, json, interface

I have a problem with deserializing the following sample JSON snippet:

```
{
   "list":{
       "A":{"ClassA":{"PropertyA":"test"}},
       "B":{"ClassB":{"PropertyB":"test"}}
    }
}
```

With my ClassA:

```
public class ClassA:IInterface{
   public String PropertyA{get; set;}
}
public class ClassB:IInterface{
   public String PropertyB{get; set;}
}
```

I want the JsonConverter to create a ClassA or ClassB with the PropertyA or PropertyB from the JSON. The ClassA or ClassB is embedded in a Dictionary.

I can also put the full class name with namespace there but I wasn't really able to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I think that's not a valid json. The enclosing brackets are missing and there is no list syntax

Comment: Its just a snippet. I will update.

Comment: For lists you need `[]`

Comment: It looks like you need to use `$type`: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm.

Comment: Sorry my fault. Its embedded into a Dictionary<String,IInterface>

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper class:

```
public class ListClass
{
    public WrapperList List { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperList
{
    public WrapperA A { get; set; }
    public WrapperB B { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperA
{
    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperB
{
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : IInterface
{
    public String PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : IInterface
{
    public String PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListClass>(json);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid those wrapper classes.
But thanks for you help

Comment: You can't, the wrappers are reflecting the json you provided. If you can change the json, then you should be able to get rid of the wrappers. The ideal json would be just: { "ClassA": { "PropertyA": "test" }, "ClassB":
 { "PropertyB": "test" } }